# JSONpath to access a JSON array element by values in multiple sibling array elements

Tags: json, rest, soapui, jsonpath

I have a service that returns a JSON two dimensional list.  I need to find a value in the second dimension based of the values of two of that elements siblings.

A sublisting of this JSON response looks like this:

```
{
 "rows" :
 [
  ["15053518617",
   "MyItemName",
   "CallActivityActivated",
   "4",
   "354687456539856756757577547674562234",
   "CallActivity",
   "2010913-e8345ac7-6c54-4835-933b-3f7ddd2dd777",
   "B0012345-2017-01-13",
   "Activated",
   "",
   "\"null\""
  ],
  ...more rows...
 ]
}
```

I need to access element 7 in this array element. But, I don't know the order in which these rows will be returned. So I need `JSONPATH` syntax I can use in a SoapUI Property transfer to identify this row by a combination of two other elements in this row.

I can access the row with hard-coded values in this particular response with:

```
$.rows.[0].[7]
```

This returns:

```
B0012345-2017-01-13
```

Because I can't depend on the rows being in the same order  (Unlike the first dimension, the order of the elements in the second dimension is consistent.)

I need to be able to replace "[0]" with a query that will return that array offset by finding two siblings of the target value in the second dimension:

```
$.rows.[?([1] == 'MyItemName' AND [2] == 'CallActivityActivated')].[7]
```

That syntax does not work. I just get back [null]. I have tried many combinations. Listing them all here would just add clutter.

Can anyone explain how to construct the necessary JSONPATH statement?